# Get an array of bytes from a datagridview

Tags: c#, sql

I have a datagridview that are connected to a table in SQL database.
There is a column of type `VARBINARY(MAX)` that store a sequence of bytes.
How can I extract these bytes from the grid view?

my code is:

```
byte [] a = datagridview.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value;
```

in which `cell[4]` contain the bytes.

but it gives an error:

> cannot implicitly convert type Object To byte[]

Comment: Cast the `Object` to `byte[]`?

Answer (score 1):

Try casting the right hand side like this

```
byte [] a = (byte [])datagridview.CurrentRow.Cells[4].Value;
```